# Camel: Concurrent consumers, process file in route by order of arrival

Tags: apache-camel

I have a scenario: where I have 2 routes, one of my routes is used to download the file from FTP Server and put it in Local directory.
Second route will pick the file from local directory and start processing further.

Multiple files can arrive on FTP at any time. Second route uses thread pool(default 10 consumers) and as files are downloaded to local directory, second route will pick those file and start processing. 
But this route picks the file randomly from local directory. I want second route to pick the file as per the timestamp.

So in case if second route is processing 10 files (as there are 10 threads configured) currently and if more files arrive at local directory then if any consumer gets free it should pick the file 
from local directory which came first.

Can anyone please guide as how can I achieve this?

Comment: You can tell the file consumer to sort the files by timestamp.

Comment: Yes @ClausIbsen it worked as expected. Thanks!